# Auto generating UI

Tags: java, user-interface, code-generation

I am writting an application that autogenerated the data input UI from a java bean.

Now i have a bean that has other beans as a property. eg User has property username, and usertype of type UserType;

Whats the best strategy in java. Do i loop through the fields in an if else loop?
eg.  get field list
       if field is of type text 
            use text field
       else if field is a number
            user a number field  etc.

is there a shortcut to the ifs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/JGoodiesBindingBeanAdapterExample.htm) of data binding using JGoodies.

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend you [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org/).

Answer (score 1):

you can also check spring Roo @ http://www.springsource.org/roo/start